# How to get from and to values in IonRangeSlider when type is 'single'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ion-range-slider

I am using IonRangeSlider in which I have 3 custom values :

```
["Value1","Value2","Value3"]
```

And the type is `single`.

Now what I want is , I want to detect the from and to values in a way If I switch from `Value1` to `Value2` then I want both of them values in 2 different variables as I have some calculations based on from and to values. But what I am able to do is just can get the From value like `Value1`.

Below is my code.

```
$('#Strategy').ionRangeSlider({
      type: 'single',
      grid: true,
      values: ["Value1","Value2","Value3"],
      onFinish: function (obj) {                
          alert(obj.from_value);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaaw56bk/69/)**.

In the `single` case the `to` is always `null` if you look inside the response parameter of `onFinish` callback, but also the first item of the passed array will be always the `to` so you could just get the both `from/to` like :

```
var maintenanceStrategyItems = ["Preventive","Optimal","Corrective"];
var old_value=maintenanceStrategyItems[0];

$('#Strategy').ionRangeSlider({
  type: 'single',
  grid: true,
  values: maintenanceStrategyItems,
  onChange: function (data) {
    console.log(old_value, data.from_value);
    old_value=data.from_value;
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var maintenanceStrategyItems = ["Preventive","Optimal","Corrective"];
var old_value=maintenanceStrategyItems[0];

$('#Strategy').ionRangeSlider({
  type: 'single',
  grid: true,
  values: maintenanceStrategyItems,
  onChange: function (data) {
    console.log(old_value, data.from_value);
    old_value=data.from_value;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Strategy" value="" />
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply but what i want is when i change from Optimal to Corrective than i want from = 'Optimal' and to = 'Corrective'. But in your case the from value is always 'Preventive'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean :( do you want to store the old selected value? (please if you don't mean by `from/to` the reserved keywords of `ionRangeSlider` let me know).

Comment: Yes exactly , i can do that with hidden field but i want it directly from the slider changes :)